# How to find identical byte[]-objects in two arrays concurrently?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, hash, hash-collision

I'm trying to implement an collision attack on hashes (I'm visiting the course 'cryptography'). Therefore I have two arrays of hashes (= byte-sequences `byte[]`) and want to find hashes which are present in both arrays. After some research and a lot of thinking I am sure that the best solution on a single-core machine would be a `HashSet` (add all elements of the first array and check via `contains` if elements of the second array are already present).

However, I want to implement a concurrent solution, since I have access to a machine with 8 cores and 12 GB RAM. The best solution I can think of is ConcurrentHashSet, which could be created via `Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<A,B>())`. Using this data structure I could add all elements of the first array in parallel and - after all elements where added - I can concurrently check via `contains` for identical hashes.

So my question is: Do you know an algorithm designed for this exact problem? If not, do you have experience using such a ConcurrentHashSet concerning problems and effective runtime complexity? Or can you recommend another prebuilt data structure which could help me?

PS: If anyone is interested in the details: I plan to use [Skandium](http://skandium.niclabs.cl/documentation/) to parallelize my program.

Comment: Are the arrays already sorted? If so, a one-pass-through merge like function will find duplicates. Otherwise you could sort array1 and array2 in parallel and do the merge on the results.

Comment: By byte hashes do you mean that all hashes are in the interval 0-255?

Comment: I meant byte-sequences, i.e. `byte[]`. They are the result of a hash-function like SHA or MD5. No, the arrays aren't sorted. Sorting and merging them would need O(n log n) for sorting and O(n + m) for merging. I hoped for a higher efficiency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it would be a complete waste of time to use any form of `HashMap`. I am guessing you are calculating multi-byte hashes of various data, these are already `hash`es, there is no need to perform any more hashing on them.

Although you do not state it, I am guessing your hashes are `byte` sequences. Clearly either a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) or a [dawg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acyclic_deterministic_finite_automaton) would be ideal to store these.

I would suggest therefore you implement a `trie/dawg` and use it to store all of the hashes in the first array. You could then use all of your computing power in parallel to lookup each element in your second array in this `trie`. No locks would be required.

**Added**

Here's a simple `Dawg` implementation I knocked together. It seems to work.

```
public class Dawg {
  // All my children.
  Dawg[] children = new Dawg[256];
  // Am I a leaf.
  boolean isLeaf = false;

  // Add a new word.
  public void add ( byte[] word ) {
    // Finds its location, growing as necessary.
    Dawg loc = find ( word, 0, true );
    loc.isLeaf = true;
  }

  // String form.
  public void add ( String word ) {
    add(word.getBytes());
  }

  // Returns true if word is in the dawg.
  public boolean contains ( byte [] word ) {
    // Finds its location, no growing allowed.
    Dawg d = find ( word, 0, false );
    return d != null && d.isLeaf; 
  }

  // String form.
  public boolean contains ( String word ) {
    return contains(word.getBytes());
  }

  // Find the Dawg - growing the tree as necessary if requested.
  private Dawg find ( byte [] word, int i, boolean grow ) {
    Dawg child = children[word[i]];
    if ( child == null ) {
      // Not present!
      if ( grow ) {
        // Grow the tree.
        child = new Dawg();
        children[word[i]] = child;
      }
    }
    // Found it?
    if ( child != null ) {
      // More to find?
      if ( i < word.length - 1 ) {
        child = child.find(word, i+1, grow);
      }
    }
    return child;
  }

  public static void main ( String[] args ) {
    Dawg d = new Dawg();
    d.add("H");
    d.add("Hello");
    d.add("World");
    d.add("Hell");
    System.out.println("Hello is "+(d.contains("Hello")?"in":"out"));
    System.out.println("World is "+(d.contains("World")?"in":"out"));
    System.out.println("Hell is "+(d.contains("Hell")?"in":"out"));
    System.out.println("Hal is "+(d.contains("Hal")?"in":"out"));
    System.out.println("Hel is "+(d.contains("Hel")?"in":"out"));
    System.out.println("H is "+(d.contains("H")?"in":"out"));
  }
}
```

**Added**

This could be a good start at a concurrent lock-free version. These things are notoriously difficult to test so I cannot guarantee this will work but to my mind it certainly should.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReferenceArray;


public class LFDawg {
  // All my children.
  AtomicReferenceArray<LFDawg> children = new AtomicReferenceArray<LFDawg> ( 256 );
  // Am I a leaf.
  boolean isLeaf = false;

  // Add a new word.
  public void add ( byte[] word ) {
    // Finds its location, growing as necessary.
    LFDawg loc = find( word, 0, true );
    loc.isLeaf = true;
  }

  // String form.
  public void add ( String word ) {
    add( word.getBytes() );
  }

  // Returns true if word is in the dawg.
  public boolean contains ( byte[] word ) {
    // Finds its location, no growing allowed.
    LFDawg d = find( word, 0, false );
    return d != null && d.isLeaf;
  }

  // String form.
  public boolean contains ( String word ) {
    return contains( word.getBytes() );
  }

  // Find the Dawg - growing the tree as necessary if requested.
  private LFDawg find ( byte[] word, int i, boolean grow ) {
    LFDawg child = children.get( word[i] );
    if ( child == null ) {
      // Not present!
      if ( grow ) {
        // Grow the tree.
        child = new LFDawg();
        if ( !children.compareAndSet( word[i], null, child ) ) {
          // Someone else got there before me. Get the one they set.
          child = children.get( word[i] );
        }
      }
    }
    // Found it?
    if ( child != null ) {
      // More to find?
      if ( i < word.length - 1 ) {
        child = child.find( word, i + 1, grow );
      }
    }
    return child;
  }

  public static void main ( String[] args ) {
    LFDawg d = new LFDawg();
    d.add( "H" );
    d.add( "Hello" );
    d.add( "World" );
    d.add( "Hell" );
    System.out.println( "Hello is " + ( d.contains( "Hello" ) ? "in" : "out" ) );
    System.out.println( "World is " + ( d.contains( "World" ) ? "in" : "out" ) );
    System.out.println( "Hell is " + ( d.contains( "Hell" ) ? "in" : "out" ) );
    System.out.println( "Hal is " + ( d.contains( "Hal" ) ? "in" : "out" ) );
    System.out.println( "Hel is " + ( d.contains( "Hel" ) ? "in" : "out" ) );
    System.out.println( "H is " + ( d.contains( "H" ) ? "in" : "out" ) );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah you are right, I would hash hashes which sounds awful. But I couldn't think about another way using prebuilt data-structures. I thought about Tries, too, but they have lookups in O(log n) rather O(1) a HashSet has - or am I wrong about that? Besides, if I can override the hash-method of the HashSet, I could put my data directly into that, preventing the hashing of hashes. (But I couldn't see how to do it in the JavaDoc of HashSet.)

Comment: @FlorianPilz the (worst case) access time of a Trie is indeed O(log n), where n = number of "characters" in your "word". But since hashes all have the same length, this is irrelevant, as n is always the same. Also, keep in mind that O(1) is allowed to take longer than even O(e^n) for small n and its only the asymptote that is part of the O()-notation.

Comment: @nd Thanks for your comment. If I understand you right, the Trie would have O(1) best-case and worst-case, since the length of my words is constant. After some more reading I understand that HashMap and Trie are comparable in speed (especially in this scenario), so Paul is right: A Trie would be better, since I don't loose speed, but save memory and have a better worst-case runtime complexity. If I got it right, this solution yields a guaranteed O(2 * n) runtime complexity, if may arrays contain n hashes. Correct?

Comment: @Florian - Yes and No. Once the dawg is built your maximum search depth for each key is the width of the hash - 1 (because if you hit the hash length you've found a match). `n` does not enter into the equation at all which makes searching essentially O(1).

Comment: @Paul Thanks for the added source code, however I'm looking for a DAWG / Trie that can be filled and read in parallel. This way I can use the 8 cores when adding all hashes of the first array. I hope such an concurrent DAWG / Trie implementation is out there. But I'm still not sure if this is the best solution. Maybe there is an idea like dynamic programming to lower the complexity by an order of magnitude.

Comment: @Paul That's what I said. ;) The DAWG / Trie has O(1) for every operation. The runtime complexity of O(2 * n) was meant for the whole problem (adding n elements of the first array and calling contains n times to check every element of the second array).

Comment: You can certainly read this in parallel. Making it fillable in parallel may be a little more complex but certainly doable. You would need an array of `AtomicReference<Dawg>`s instead of just plain `Dawg`s and some thought on growing it in parallel would be necessary. If you would like help with this, post another question.

Comment: A short search reveals that there is no concurrent implementation of DAWGs or Tries (or they aren't popular enough to be shown in Google). So I will have to built it myself - in that case your code will be of great help, I think I will post an follow-up question in some days. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Florian - Please post a comment here when you post your follow-up. I would like to see how it all works out. - Glad to be of help.

Comment: Using `word.getBytes()` for the string form is dependent on the default encoding which means that if the default encoding changes during the life of the JVM any existing dawgs may no longer respond with true to `contains(myStr)` if `add(myStr)` was done before the encoding change.  I suggest mandating an encoding as in `word.getBytes("UTF-8")` or leaving string handling out entirely.

Comment: Thanks Mike - the String versions of the `add` and `contains` are more utility functions than core functions. They are here for ease of testing. The `byte` versions will be used in almost all cases so I would leave `String` handling out in the final version. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Yo dawg, we heard you like recursive data structures, so we put a dawg in your dawg.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach would be to just split the first array into N equal (or near-equal) parts (with 8 cores, n=8 seems reasonable).  Then solve the program in the "normal" way, by looking if any hashes in the 2nd array are present in the N smaller sub-first-arrays.  This can be done in parallel.

That said, I've never heard of tries/dawgs before and I found the main discussion fascinating and informative.  (I mainly work with numbers, not words)

This assumes that the byte[] hashes are of some finite, shortish length so that you really can split up the original file to process in parallel.  Is that the case?

EDIT ADDED

For an example of this idea, see *GPU Graphics Gems*, edited by Wen-Mei W. Hwu, chapter 11, an article by Ligowski, Rudnicki, Liu and Schmidt.  They parallelize a massive protein sequence database search by splitting the huge single database into many smaller pieces, then run the *normal algorithm* on each subpiece.  I like this quote.  "The described algorithm is embarrassingly parallel".  In their case they used CUDA and had to do a lot of memory optimization, but the principle should still apply to multi-core machines.

semi-PSEUDOCODE FOLLOWS.  I'll use Lists for the incoming byte[] hashes, hope that's o.k.

Original, 1 core method

```
originalProcess(List<byte[]> list1, List<byte[]> list2) {
   HashSet<byte[]> bigHugeHashOfList1 = new HashSet<byte[]>();
   bigHugeHashOfList1.addAll(list1);
   for (byte[] hash : list2)
      if (bigHugeHashOfList1.contains(hash)
         // do something
}
```

New method.  Uses exact same process method (later on).  No DAWGS or TRIES here...

```
preprocess(List<byte[]> list1, List<byte[]> list2) {
   List<byte[]>[] splitLists = new ArrayList<byte[]>[8];
   for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
      splitLists[i] = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
   for (byte[] hash : list1) {
      int idx = hash[0]&7; // I'm taking the 3 low order bits, YMMV
      splitLists[idx].add(hash);
      // a minor speedup would be to create the HashSet here instead of in originalProcess()
   }

   // now, using your favorite parallel/concurrency technique,
   // do the equivalent of
   for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
      originalProcess(splitLists[i], list2);
}
```

Comment: Your approach is possible and simpler, but less efficient. Testing if an element is inside an Arrays of length n costs up to O(n), because you have to iterate through the array. HashMaps and Tries perform lookups in O(1), which is way faster. (Sidenote: Tries can normally have a lookup time of O(m), where m is the length of the word. In this special case all words have the same (constant) length, therefore it has no effect on the  big-O-notation.)

Comment: You could still use a HashMap for the N smaller sub-problems. Just like your original single-core solution.  That's what I meant by the "normal" way.  An advantage is that they need not be Concurrent.

Comment: You could split across 8 cores by taking the first 3 bits of the hash as a discriminator. This would be an excellent first step.

Comment: Yeah, a hash would be better. But now it's the exact same solution I proposed with the ConcurrentHashSet. @Paul You are right, that would be an excellent first step and I thought about it. I'm not sure if that improves the speed of the algorithm, but requires some clever splitting-algorithm to divide them by the first x bit (remember: the arrays aren't sorted). Maybe you could elaborate on that idea. :)

Comment: @Florian Yes, _it is_ the exact same solution you proposed with a HashSet.  That's the point.  You have parallelized "strategically", not "tactically".  Please see edits in my answer for more info.

Comment: Don't get your 'strategically' vs 'tactically' statement. And the algorithm is the same for both ideas: HashSets and DAWG / Tries, since I only use `add` and `contains`. Besides, I don't see the point why you post an answer that is identical to a solution I wrote in the question. I'm sure you have something in mind, but I still can't see your point - please elaborate. PS: Could you set a link to the paper you are referring? (Write `[Link](Linklocation)`.)

Comment: @Florian see added pseudocode.  I have a physical book for the article, I don't think there is an online version, but try some Googling.

Comment: OK, I understood you correctly. :) Yes, your solution is simpler and is as fast as the DAWG / Trie variant. Because I think the memory efficiency of a DAWG / Trie is worth the effort of building it, I will implement the solution Paul proposed rather than yours. I thank you for your time to develop another idea and discuss it with me.

Comment: Yes, my solution is a memory hog.  Let us know how trie dawg work.  How about an upvote?